# How to change u-boot logo - Yocto

Tags: u-boot, yocto

I'm using Yocto (VERSION = "2.7.1 (warrior)"
) - raspberry pi 4. How can I change the raspberry logo - in the upper left corner during startup.

What is the path to the image file.
I checked most files in U-Boot. Where is the script calculating the number of cores?

Comment: Maybe your [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45788396/yocto-raspberry-pi-change-psplash-image), it is define [here](https://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit/cgit.cgi/meta-raspberrypi/tree/conf/machine/include/rpi-base.inc#n81)

Comment: The [psplash-raspberrypi-img.h](https://github.com/gbraad/yocto-meta-raspi/blob/master/recipes-core/psplash/files/psplash-raspberrypi-img.h) - YOu can modify the image stored in `POKY_IMG_RLE_PIXEL_DATA` or use [make-image-header.sh](https://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit/cgit.cgi/psplash/tree/make-image-header.sh)

Comment: More [infos](https://developer.gnome.org/gdk-pixbuf/stable/gdk-pixbuf-csource.html) : `gdk-pixbuf-csource` with parameter `--macros` , example : `gdk-pixbuf-csource --macros mypicture.bmp > psplash-raspberrypi-img.h` (use the same size of the orignal picture for your input image)